# How to save flash games on android?

Tags: android, flash, super-mario-crossover

Playing a downloadable version of Super Mario Crossover on an Android tablet. Playing online requires adobe flash player. Google no longer allows Adobe flash player for android. That's why i have to use the downloadable version of the game (google & adobe are fighting right now). So I'm using Flash Game Player app from play store. The in-game save & load feature doesn't work for the downloadable version. Plus i hear loading & saving progress in flash games is a tough deal to begin with. Does anybody know how to save & load flash games on android?

Comment: The first idea that I thought of would be to jail break your phone.  And depending on your type of phone, you might be able to save (and load) to a memory chip.

Answer (score -1):

Try to play mobile games. Through sites. most of them use downloadable versions of players for games, so there is no need to install the player. Check for http://iospace.games/shellshockio  as an example. In most cases these games go without special presets even on tablet versions.